# Vmware VM shows old CPU after vMotion to faster CPU of same generation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, central-processing-unit, vmotion

I have struggled to find any official documentation on what I should expect to happen when vmotioning a VM from one host, to another than has the same generation CPU but different model.

The VM runs as expected, but it still shows the old CPU model and clock speed in both device manager and task manager.

Host A is an E5-2640v2 @ 2Ghz, and host B is an E5-2695v2 @ 2.4Ghz.

Can anyone tell me if I should expect the VM to update the CPU identifier to match the new host's CPU model, or will it always remain as the initial model? Note, I have tried a reboot, but even still it shows the old 2640 model CPU.

I would guess the VM is in fact running at the new clock speed of host B, but it would be beneficial to actually see this as true from within the guest VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have experienced the same thing. If you do benchmarks, the CPU will perform at the rate that it should for the higher clock speed. I Believe if you restart the VM, it will show the new clock speed as well.

Comment: Did try restarting the VM, but still had the old CPU ID. I might try CPU-Z as well, see what that reports

Comment: Looks like after several restarts, the CPU ID was displayed correctly.